# Only show InfiniteProgress if task takes longer than a set time

Tags: codenameone

I use InfiniteProgress throughout my app when loading pages such as below code: -

Dialog ip = new InfiniteProgress().showInfiniteBlocking();

//Load Page

ip.dispose();

Depending on the connection, this process may be very fast or take longer. The result is often the screen appears to flicker which is undesirable. I would like to only show the InfiniteProgress indication if the process takes longer than say 1 second. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite know about the platform you're using, but how about setting a timeout to show the dialog, and if the page load happens to finish before the timeout triggers, cancel it?

Comment: Yes. You can use a `UITimer` for this purpose. There's no automation of that aspect at this time.